# why vue watch object can use non string as key?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, watch

```
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
```

i have googled extensively and read api and tutorial docs on vue official website.

i remember js object has to use string for keys, but in the object of vue watch, you can clearly see from the above example (copied from vue router) that 1) the key is an object, not a string; 2) it's not even using this.$route, but can instead directly referencing things without this (vm instance)

could anyone help understand this? thanks.

Comment: That's a method (new in ES6), and the key is still a string. They key is `'$route'` and the value is a function.

Comment: this is equivalent shorthand for `$route: function (to, from) {` - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Comment: hi @Li357 and Jaromanda X, thank you both.

i know this ES6 feature and i know it means $route: function () {}. let's say it's written in the form of $route: function () {}, so to confirm:
here it's actually "$route", not using the the object ref $route, and Vue will automatically use the string "$route" to find the object ref with the same name? thanks.

Comment: @user3236895 Yes, exactly.